# Google analytics double reporting

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am trying to determine if my google analytics are being reported twice based on the javascript below in my page.  I dont have to have the second script in there to make it work as far as I know, but I am trying to determine if page views/sessions were being recorded twice based off of this configuration.  If anyone can provide a test I can do to find this out myself i would appreciate that as well.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];

        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXXX-3']);
        _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'mywebsite.com']);
        _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

        (function() {
            var ga = document.createElement('script');
            ga.type = 'text/javascript';
            ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js"></script>
```

Comment: GA code should not be double counting because of this. However, you shouldn't do this for performance reasons. You should look for the actual requests to google. Use your browser's dev tools to look at network traffic or any number of addons and programs designed to look at requests.

Comment: This will not lead to double counting but the last script tag is useless and will lead to protocol errors in ssl pages. What exactly are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: I am transitioning from Jahia to Magnolia CMS.  This was the script inside Jahia and I am using the Magnolia built in GA module, which seems to be reporting more correct numbers.  I need to find out what exactly this script reports and provide proof that it is reporting incorrectly somehow, or just how it reported differently.  Right now all I know is that it is different, not how.